# google app script insert date to table using jdbc

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to insert a date in one of my Oracle table, I tried use setTimestamp, setDate and even setObject but none of these methods work. Anyone know what is the correct way to insert date value?

```
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into blob_table (filename,blob_field,date_insert) values (?,?,?)");
var date_insert=new Date();

stmt.setString(1, mess.getAttachments()[0].getName());
stmt.setBytes(2, mess.getAttachments()[0].getBytes());
//stmt.setTimestamp(3,(JdbcTimestamp)date_insert.getTime);
stmt.setObject(3, date_insert);
//stmt.setDate(3,date_insert.getDate() );
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `Jdbc.newTimestamp` method to create a `JdbcTimestamp` object, as [documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#newTimestamp(Integer)).

Example:

```
var date_insert = new Date();
var jdbc_timestamp = Jdbc.newTimestamp(date_insert.getTime());
...
stmt.setTimestamp(x, jdbc_timestamp);
```

The same principle applies for `JdbcDate` and `JdbcTime`.

In your case:

```
var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into blob_table (filename,blob_field,date_insert) values (?,?,?)");

var date_insert = new Date();
var timestamp = Jdbc.newTimestamp(date_insert.getTime());

stmt.setString(1, mess.getAttachments()[0].getName());
stmt.setBytes(2, mess.getAttachments()[0].getBytes());
stmt.setTimestamp(3, timestamp);
```

If you need to handle specific timezones, you can use another method. In this example I'm using the same timezone as the spreadsheet I'm working on:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var js_date = new Date();
var date_str = Utilities.formatDate(js_date, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
var timestamp = Jdbc.parseTimestamp(date_str);
stmt.setTimestamp(x, timestamp);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: When there's no spreadsheet available (standalone script) you can use "Session.getScriptTimeZone()" instead of "ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()".

Answer (score 1):

First of all convert your date into a string by the following way:

```
var stringDate=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date_insert), "GMT+05:30", "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss ");
Logger.log("stringdate  "+stringDate);
```

now use set object :

```
stmt.setObject(3,stringDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Oracle expert and but in the past, I've actually pushed the current time calculation into Oracle/DB rather than doing this in the application layer (Apps Script here). Oracle (like other DBs) has a "current time" calculation macro/special function. So if you re-write your INSERT statement like this - 
From -

> insert into blob_table (filename,blob_field,date_insert) values
>   (?,?,?)

To -

> insert into blob_table (filename,blob_field,date_insert) values
>   (?,?,**CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**)

Then you no longer need to pass in a time from Apps Script. You can see more [recipes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions037.htm) on the Oracle docs with formatting and timezone handling.  This will also make your code simpler by a couple of lines.

Comment: it's just a sample to show how to set parameter with date data type

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a library to work with JDBC databases (and spreadsheets), and that easily handles dates/times in a MySQL database. Would you like to try it and tell me if it works equally well in Oracle?

http://www.harryonline.net/scripts/objdb-storing-data-with-google-apps-script/482